# JavaFXの実装について

Tags: javafx

JavaFXの実装についてです。
Eclipse内で以下の様なエラーが出てしまいます。自分なりに調べ以下のような準備は整えましたが、一向に変化がありません。

- eclipse  2019 - 3
- Java 11
- e(fx)clipse  3 .5 .0
- Open JFX （正直ここが調べても少しわかりません）

  - javafx-jmods-13
  - javafx-sdk-13

改善点があればご指摘お願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**追記**

```java
package application;

import org.graalvm.compiler.phases.common.NodeCounterPhase.Stage;

import com.apple.eawt.Application;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: OpenJFXのEclipseについてマニュアル https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse を読んで、この通りに実施したのにEclipse上で認識されないということですか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/193781

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX SDKとGraalVMコンパイラーのライブラリ(jarファイル)がビルドパスに設定されていないので、それらをダウンロードして、ビルドパスに追加して下さい。それから、`Main`クラスの中に存在しないメソッドを呼び出している箇所もあるようです。

JavaFX SDK
https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

GraalVMコンパイラー
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.compiler/compiler/1.0.0-rc16

**追記**

importがおかしいです。javafxのクラスをインポートすべきところで、

```java
import org.graalvm.compiler.phases.common.NodeCounterPhase.Stage;
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
```

無関係な同名のクラスをインポートしています。以下の2行に変更して下さい。

```java
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
```

それから、GraalVMコンパイラーのライブラリは不要無いのでビルドパスから除いて下さい。これでビルドは通るようになります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。[ビルド・パス]の[外部アーカイブに追加]で写真ようにフォルダにJavaFX SDKとGraalVMコンパイラーを入れました。これは、右の箇所を修正すればJava Fxが出来るのでしょうか？（写真URLになります➡︎）https://d.kuku.lu/20245f13d4

Comment: ありがとうございます。先ほどのホルダーからはエラーが消えました。ですがScenesBuilderをfxmlファイルから開く際、画像のの様なアラートが出てしまいます。　また、新しいJavaFXファイルを作成してもてもエラーになってしまいました。https://d.kuku.lu/358cedad68

Comment: [これ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096331/error-opening-scene-builder)の最多票の回答で解決するのでは。